# pattern for objects with and without context

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I'm working on a system that is composed generically of questions and answers. Users of the system can use the ideas of questions and answers to design questionnaires.

When authoring questionnaires there is one type of question. Once a question is created, different types of answers can be added to it. For example, boolean answers, text answers, etc..

When executing & displaying questionnaires, the types of answers that have been added to the question are relevant in the context of the question when displaying it. So when drawing a question on the screen, I need to know what kind of answers it has, to know how to mark it up/draw it on the screen.

So there is tension between the domain ideas when considering them in either context.

The type of questions are in some ways defined by the types of answers, but I'm also not sure it's right to have multiple types of questions, one for each possible type of answer combination during authoring.

That being said, I don't feel like it's right to have to inspect the children of (answers within) the question - each time I need to figure out how to display it.

I'm confident that this kind of problem can be addressed with existing patterns, and that I just don't have the language to articulate it.

If anyone can help me re-frame this with a pattern I'd appreciate it.

Comment: It seems strange to me that a question does't know what answer types it can have. Does the question include some English text that asks the question? If so I'd think that would determine the answer types.

Comment: Can a single instance of a Question have multiple answer types?  If so, you prioritize among the answers (some hierarchy to pick one) or do you draw respecting all of them?

Comment: I understood the questions as **model** and the form of the answer as **view**, that depends on the context. You can answer 5 + 5 with a straight answer (= 10), or check the right box, if the answering form is multiple choice ([x] 10, [ ] 55).

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth - questions are generic, and although they know at design time what types of answers can be added to their answer collection. They aren't 'defined' by the type of answers that are added. Questions also have messages (which include text) and the designer needs to ensure that the text of the message is relevant to the type of answer being requested.

Comment: @karakfa - What a good question. :) 
A single instance of a question can have multiple types of answers but in cases where the answer is composed of multiple pieces of information the answer is encapsulated as a single composite answer type. So I guess the answer is no. A question cannot have multiple answer types at the same time.

Comment: @mike - you are totally right that there is a view component here but that's outside the scope of the question. Answers can have different fundamental types irrespective of the way they are displayed to the user. For example, boolean answers can be displayed as check boxes, or drop downs, or radio buttons, but they are still boolean answers which are different from date answers, and text answers, etc..